# Ternary Operator concatenate $variable

Tags: php

i feel lost with this thing.

```
<?php
$check = '1';

function showOptions($value, $dbh) {
    $dbh1 = $dbh;
    $value1 = $value;

    echo '<div class"myclass">'.$value1.'</div>';
}

 $options = showOptions ("Hello World!", 'db');
 $tabs = ($check != '2' ? '<div id="tabs-5" class="panel">'.$options.'</div>' : '');
 echo $tabs;
?>
```

as result is get:

```
<div class"myclass">Hello World!</div>
<div id="tabs-5" class="panel"></div>
```

instead of:

```
<div id="tabs-5" class="panel"><div class"myclass">Hello World!</div></div>
```

how do i concatenate it correctly ?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change your `echo` statement in the function to a `return` statement like this:

(Otherwise you don't return anything and in the variable `$options` nothing get's saved)

```
function showOptions($value, $dbh) {
    $dbh1 = $dbh;
    $value1 = $value;

    return '<div class"myclass">'.$value1.'</div>';
  //^^^^^^ See here return instead of echo
}

 $options = showOptions ("Hello World!", 'db');
```